# How can I ignore a line in a batch file that uses carets for line continuation?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Take this example that uses carets for line continuation:

```
echo ^
aaa ^
bbb ^
ccc ^
ddd
```

How can I effectively "comment out" the `bbb` line so that it is ignored when running the batch file?

Comment: Can't you just `REM` the line out?

Comment: Try to put `%=` at the beginning of the line and `=%` just before _space_ + `^`; this defines an invalid variable name (because of `=`) that cannot even become set; this fails if the line contains `%`-signs or `:~`. *N. B.:* You should begin each continued line with a _space_, because the `^` in the previous line actually escapes the first character of that line, which could lead to unexpected side effects…

Comment: @SomethingDark I've tried REM and ::. Seems those only work at the beginning of a line. When using carets for line continuation, it's the equivalent of putting REM right in the middle of the command which causes it to be interpreted literally.

Comment: @aschipfl It works, but it's fickle. See edit to OP which uses `echo` for the example so you can try it yourself. Using your method of `%=bbb=% ^` causes the command to output `aaa  ccc ddd`. Still renders a space. I tried removing the space, but the batch file doesn't seem to like `%^` together. This appears to be the closest solution, though I'd like one that outputs a zero-length string for that line. Edit: Also, if I put a space at the beginning of each line, I will still have to put one at the end, so it would render two spaces.

Comment: @flemming, why not remove the unnecessary space before the caret then? ```%=bbb=%^```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo aaa <nul ^
%=bbb =%< nul ^
ccc ^
ddd
```

Looks odd, but it's necessary because the caret at the end of a line has also the effect, that the first character of the next line is also escaped.
But redirections are able to remove the effect, and they can also remove single characters or even complete tokens from the output

That is the problem if you try:

```
echo aaa ^
%=bbb =%^
ccc
```

The percent expression expands to nothing, so the code it's equal to.

```
echo aaa^
^
ccc
```

That is equal to:

```
echo aaa^^
ccc
```

And now ccc is treated as a new command

Answer (score 1):

First change the start line to the following.

```
echo^
 aaa^
 bbb^
 ccc^
 ddd
```

This way it is always guaranteed that the caret will escape the space on the following line and not something that should not be escaped.

If everything before the caret is hidden from cmd then the caret from the previous line will escape that caret and line-continuation gets broken.
So there needs to be something to be escaped by the caret of the aaa line.
This is why the space is necessary.
But an escaped space is still a space and visible with echo.
This space can be hidden in the echo by adding a backspace.

Method 1: transform line to a non-existing variable.

This method makes 'bbb' disappear by changing it to a non-existant variable.   This method has been mentioned by others.

So change [SPACE]bbb^
to        [SPACE][BS]%=bbb=%^

Method 2: make the line disappear by inserting a NUL character.

This method does something similar but turns the bbb-line into a sort of end-of-line-comment by inserting a NUL character.

So change [SPACE]bbb^
to        [SPACE][BS][NUL]bbb^

How does this work?
The interpreter stops processing characters when it encounters a null character and skips the null and everything following it including the next CRLF.

Both methods have their pro's and con's.
The first is generally editor-friendly (editor needs to support backspace), but fails with 'b%b'.
The second is very editor-unfriendly (editor needs to support backspace and null-character), but will work on all text replacing 'bbb'.
The first can be used in command blocks and with with redirections.
The second might fail with command blocks and redirections, but i have done only minimal tests with these.

Both methods work ok for the in between lines of the continuation, but not for the first and last.

Comment: But can you use the second method to comment out only line "bbb", but still append "ccc"? IMHO, using NUL will prevent any further line continuations

Comment: @jeb The NUL is (error)handled in the earliest phase of processing, when the source is read line by line. The NUL causes the reader to ignore the remaining characters including the CRLF and the preceding caret. The only thing that remains of the bbb line is the space BackSpace at the start. The ccc line will continue with one notable change, the space at the start will not be escaped (the caret of line aaa escapes space of line bbb, and the caret of line bbb is gone because of the NUL).

Comment: Interesting, I never know that NUL removes CR/LF or I forgot it. Before, I thought it's more or less equal to a _raw_ LF character, but a _raw_ LF only removes all content to the line end, but the CR/LF is recognized, therefor it doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "bbb=bbb"

echo ^
aaa ^
%bbb% ^
ccc ^
ddd

SET "bbb="

echo ^
aaa ^
%bbb% ^
ccc ^
ddd

GOTO :EOF
```

**The character `set` in the second example is a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (`^H`).** This doesn't work for the very first element (`aaa`)